# Unlocking the bootloader Huawei P8 Lite 2017 (PRA-LX1(C02)

Tags: 7.0-nougat, huawei, 8.0-oreo, emui

I'd like to have my bootloader unlocked for my Huawei P8 Lite 2017 (PRA-LX1(C02)), but I don't wanna spend money on DC-Unlocker. My phone runs Android 8.0 EMUI 8.0 but I can downgrade it to Android 7.0 if needed. If you need IMEI, Serial Numbers things like that ask me and I'll provide those.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: so your question is where to get unlock code for free

Comment: basically yes if you know where I can get it please tell me thanks