# What is a SLOCK file and how I can get it (Huawei Bootloader)

Tags: rooting, huawei, bootloader-lock

I found this post on the XDA Forum (https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unlock-bootloader-for-free.4054619/) to unlock the bootloader of phones that have Kirin 970/710 and lower and with EMUI 8.0 with June patch. I have everything for unlocking it but they stopped giving the SLOCK file indefinitely (at least for now).

> The SLOCK service has been permanently terminated.
> Our TPM has stopped functioning completely because it reached it's lifespan and Huawei's root certificate is now expired.
> Thanks for being here for these 4 years we've been collaborating with you on issuing SLOCKs.

I would like to know what's a SLOCK file and how I can get it (or unlocking the bootloader anyway). If someone knows how I can unlock my bootloader (PRA-LX1C02) (I'm aware of DC-Unlocker and other paid services but I don't want to spend money) or the SLOCK file let me know.
Thanks in advance for everyone that replies!
P.S: A good Custom ROM with Android 10/11? Thanks

Comment: just spend that 4,- bucks on dc unlocker you have nothing to lose

Comment: https://hcu-client.com/read-bootloader-code-huawei-phone

Comment: @alecxs sorry I don't want to pay for a code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unlocking the bootloader Huawei P8 Lite 2017 (PRA-LX1(C02)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230882/unlocking-the-bootloader-huawei-p8-lite-2017-pra-lx1c02)

Comment: @alecxs no since no one gave me a clue or direction for unlocking it for free